# BAD REQUEST 400 when trying to use variable to change discord.Colour

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am adding profile cards onto my Discord bot so users can choose what color they want in their embeds, but each time I attempt to use a variable  with discord.Colour, I get an error.

```
color = '0x2897ff'
embed = discord.Embed(title="Profile", colour=discord.Colour(color))
```

Always causes this:

> BAD REQUEST (status code: 400)

However,

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Profile", colour=discord.Colour(0x2897ff))
```

works fine. But I need to be able to put variables there somehow so I can let users change their profile colors.

Any help would mean a lot, thank you.

Comment: Create an enumeration of colors?

Comment: `'0x2897ff'` is not the same as `0x2897ff`.

Comment: Odd that it throws 400. Something going wrong *in code* should clearly be something in the 500 category... If I were using Discord, I might consider figuring out why and file a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
colour = '0x2897ff'
```

use:

```
colour = 0x2897ff
```

`'0x2897ff'` is a string but `0x2897ff` (without apostrophe) is an integer.

Comment: To add to this, if `colour` is being input as a hexadecimal number by the user, you can use `colour = int(input, 16)` to convert it to a number.